# Rails checkbox color if disabled

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 3 app index list.  I want to display a boolean column as a checkbox.

This is the code I'm using:

```
<td><%= check_box_tag 'sell', '1', costproject.rebudget, disabled: true%></td>
```

The checkboxes end up looking like this:

[image]

But, I want it to look like this (not disabled):

[image]

I can access using this CSS:

```
#sell {
  ...
}
```

But, how can I make it a colored background with white check - if checked?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try starting with these: http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-checkbox-styles http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-easy-css3-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons--webdesign-8953 You'll need to adjust your html slightly

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved several ways. The best is with css by referencing your tag as a checkbox and changing the style when the checked flag is marked.

```
#sell[type=checkbox]:checked {
    //Put your rules in here for blue colored version
}
```

The second is with js by doing the same thing, but by binding a handler to your checkbox and changing the css when it get fired.

Comment: What is the CSS to change the box to blue with white check?